# Sub-Query and having group by clause in sql

Tags: mysql

Can we write this query without using sub-query?

```
select * from test where EmpTran in
(select max(EmpTran) from test);
```

I tried this code but it returns empty set.
I read that, 'in absence of group by, entire data is taken as a single group', if that's the case the the query should return same result as the query above.

```
select EmpTran,EmpName from test
having EmpTran = max(EmpTran);
```

Sample data:

```
  create table test(EmpName varchar(10),EmpTrans int);
  insert into test values('Ans',100);
  insert into test values('Sam',50);
  insert into test values('Kar',150);
  insert into test values('Sar',200);
  insert into test values('Raj',200);
```

Comment: I would expect your first query to return something, assuming it actually has records in it.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: I can't [reproduce your problem](http://rextester.com/NLY37458) on a sample table with data in it.

Comment: `(select max(EmpTran) from test)` since this will be a single value, you can use `=` instead of `in`

Comment: We can, but why would we want to?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think "this code" refers to the second query, not the first one. The first query works, and he thinks the second one should be equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right.  Side note, using `MAX() OVER ()` as an analytic function with MySQL 8+, we can actually do something very close to this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Perhaps you can post an answer showing how to do that. I don't know window functions yet.

Comment: @Barmar I posted a tested query which is the window function way of doing this.

Comment: @Strawberry using sub-queries the performance is somewhat slow, hence, the use of single query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The following are the queries,so that you can duplicate the scenario  --create table test(EmpName varchar(10),EmpTrans int);
insert into test values('Ans',100);
insert into test values('Sam',50);
insert into test values('Kar',150);
insert into test values('Sar',200);
insert into test values('Raj',200);

Comment: @Anshuman_Jha Put the sample data in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Doing it as a single query is not likely to be any faster. It still has to do the same amount of work: First find the maximum value, then scan all the rows to see if they match that maximum. It should be fast if you add an index on the `EmpTran` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query doesn't work because as soon as you use an aggregation function anywhere in the query, it causes the rows to be aggregated. Since you don't have `GROUP BY`, everything is aggregated into a single row in the result set (just as you quoted: *in absence of group by, entire data is taken as a single group*). In this result set, `EmpTran` and `EmpName` are taken from arbitrary rows in the table (they might not even be from the same row).

`HAVING` then filters this result set. If the selected value of `EmpTran` doesn't match `MAX(EmpTran)`, the row is removed from the result set and you get an empty result.

The order of processing is:

1. Use `WHERE` to select the rows to put in the result set.
2. Aggregate the result set if necessary.
3. Use `HAVING` to filter the aggregated result set.

I don't think there's a way to do this without a subquery in MySQL 5.x. In MySQL 8.x you can do it with a window function (I'm not familiar with these, so I'm not going to show it in my answer).

Comment: "everything is aggregated into a single row in the result set" can you explain this?

Comment: It's exactly what you wrote in the question: **in absence of group by, entire data is taken as a single group**

Comment: So, what i make out of it is that, in absence of group by entire data along with meta data of the table is returned as a result set and the aggregate function doesn't differentiate each rows(in a way which we want) and hence returns an empty set and also at times it can return unexpected values. Am I right?

Comment: The non-grouped aggregation creates a result set of 1 row. Then HAVING checks whether that row matches its condition. If it does, the row is returned; otherwise, an empty result is returned.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar has already explained, your second query won't work because finding the max of a column requires a formal separate subquery.  This was the case for MySQL versions earlier than 8+.  Starting with MySQL 8+, which introduced window functions, we could try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, MAX(EmpTran) OVER () max_val
    FROM test
) t
WHERE EmpTran = max_val;
```

### Demo

The demo is in SQL Server, because Rextester does not yet support MySQL 8+.  But, it should run on any database which implements the ANSI standard for window functions.

Comment: My second query won't work because finding the max of a column requires a formal separate sub-query, but for that purpose we have **group by and having**. And in absence of group by the entire data is considered as one group hence it should have worked.

Comment: @Anshuman_Jha No, your second query would not even _run_ on most other databases.  When you invoke `MAX` without `GROUP BY`, you are telling the database to do stuff at the entire table level, not at the level of individual records.  So, your second query does not even make any sense.

Comment: "do stuff at the entire table level" is this not same as all the rows in the table?

Comment: No, it's not.  You either run the query in group/table mode, or record level mode.  Actually, my answer sort of does both, doing a query while at the same time turning out a table level max.  But, it still requires a subquery.